# FPDF-PHP pdf generation issue

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am trying to print the value from MySQL table to the PDFs using fpdf lib.

The following is the code sample:

```
$dcr_query="SELECT * FROM `incident_investigation` where ii_reference_no='$ref_num' and ii_company_id='$compny_id'";

 $result_1 = mysql_query ($dcr_query) or ErrorHandler (array ('File' => __FILE__,'Line' => __LINE__,'SqlErr' =>mysql_error(),'SqlQry' => $dcr_query));
 while($row_apr = mysql_fetch_array($result_1)) { 

$method=$row_apr['ii_method'];

$pdf->SetY(50);
$pdf->SetX(35);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,5,$method); 

}
```

for example:
The values of ***$method*** from the MySQL table is 'test method1' | 'test method2' | 'test method3' etc...
So the out put in PDF should be like :

test method1 
test method2 
test method2

I want the `$method` line by line.How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this inside the loop,

```html
    $variable = $row['method']
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(25);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $variable, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
```

[you can use this reference also](http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/30/)